# Querying Large SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list

What are the considerations that, one needs to be aware of when querying a large SharePoint list of 16000+ items.

They query will return only 1 row. Is this a feasible use case, or should I look for a Database.

How can one measure performance when querying a large SharePoint list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you work with SharePoint lists is how to address the performance degradation that can occur when your list contains a large number of items. However, SharePoint is capable of managing extremely large lists containing millions of rows. The often-quoted limit of 2,000 items per list, actually refers to the maximum number of items that you should retrieve in a single query or view in order to avoid performance degradation. Effective **indexing** and **query throttling** strategies can help you to improve the performance of large lists.

[Handling Large Folders and Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557257%28office.14%29.aspx)

How Does Indexing Affect Throttling?
The list view threshold does not apply simply to the number of results returned by your query. Instead, it restricts the numbers of database rows that can be accessed in order to complete execution of the query at the row level in the content database. For example, suppose you are working with a list that contains 10,000 items. If you were to build a query that returns the first 100 items sorted by the ID field, the query would execute without issue because the ID column is always indexed. However, if you were to build a query that returns the first 100 items sorted by a non-indexed Title field, the query would have to scan all 10,000 rows in the content database in order to determine the sort order by **title** before returning the first 100 items. Because of this, the query would be throttled, and rightly so—this is a resource-intensive operation.

In this case, you could avoid the issue by indexing the **Title field**. This would enable SharePoint to determine the top 100 items sorted by title from the index without scanning all 10,000 list items in the database. The same concepts that apply to sort operations also apply to **where clauses** and **join** predicates in list queries. Careful use of column indexing can mitigate many large list performance issues and help you to avoid query throttling limits.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798465.aspx

Comment: So lets say if I have a Title Field, a Description Field and keywords fields, and I were to filter by Title or keywords field, I would need index Title and Keywords in SharePoint?

Comment: Yes, To avoid the Performance issue.